# Yarn command line output does not match package.json file

Tags: npm, socket.io, yarnpkg

After running yarn upgrade per the [usage docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage), I get this output:

[image]

and it appears that I have been updated to

**socket.io@2.1.1**

However when I look at my package.json file I have this line

```
"socket.io": "^2.0.4",
```

Is there a way to verify which version I have installed and also is there a way to resolve this seeming discrepancy?

Also, there is this strange line in the yarn.lock file:

```
socket.io@^2.0.4:
  version "2.1.1"
```

How can I understand what is going on here as these 3 sources seem to say different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `yarn list --pattern socket.io` to verify currently installed version.

`"socket.io": "^2.0.4"`
in package.json means version 2.0.4 or any newer in 2.x.x range.

`socket.io@^2.0.4:`
 `version "2.1.1"`
in yarn.lock means that ^2.0.4 was satisfied by installing version 2.1.1 (is newer than 2.0.4 and in the same time is in 2.x.x range).

See [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)